# rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (56591 bytes received so far)

Tags: rsync

Suddenly `rsync (3.1.0 client, 3.0.1  server)` started intermittently failing after initially transferring about 56KB. When I keep trying the same command it eventually succeeds. Pings and other networking tests look normal. Here are the results:

```
alecm@dev2 ~/im/push> rsync -rlptcz --exclude="config.*" --exclude=logs --exclude=weblogs --exclude=red5 --exclude="start_server.sh" --exclude=keys --exclude="stop_server.sh" --exclude="robots.txt" --exclude="livepush.cfg" --exclude="command_pipe" --delete --force --stats -e ssh $BUILDDIR/im $PUSH_HOST:/nail/push
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (56591 bytes received so far) [generator]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(359)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(837) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Keep trying till it eventually succeeds:

```
alecm@dev2 ~/im/push> rsync -rlptcz --exclude="config.*" --exclude=logs --exclude=weblogs --exclude=red5 --exclude="start_server.sh" --exclude=keys --exclude="stop_server.sh" --exclude="robots.txt" --exclude="livepush.cfg" --exclude="command_pipe" --delete --force --stats -e ssh $BUILDDIR/im $PUSH_HOST:/nail/push

Number of files: 1,488 (reg: 1,394, dir: 94)
Number of regular files transferred: 182
Total file size: 41,240,607 bytes
Total transferred file size: 4,080,560 bytes
Literal data: 2,073,945 bytes
Matched data: 2,006,615 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.122 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 2,090,800
Total bytes received: 22,468
```

Verify success:

```
alecm@dev2 ~/im/push> rsync -rlptcz --exclude="config.*" --exclude=logs --exclude=weblogs --exclude=red5 --exclude="start_server.sh" --exclude=keys --exclude="stop_server.sh" --exclude="robots.txt" --exclude="livepush.cfg" --exclude="command_pipe" --delete --force --stats -e ssh $BUILDDIR/im $PUSH_HOST:/nail/push

Number of files: 1,488 (reg: 1,394, dir: 94)
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 41,240,607 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 0
File list generation time: 0.116 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 56,595
Total bytes received: 16

sent 56,595 bytes  received 16 bytes  16,174.57 bytes/sec
total size is 41,240,607  speedup is 728.49
```

Until recently it all worked without any changes or updates. I noticed that it always fails with about 56591 bytes sent, but after it succeeds and I verify that everything is synced, it shows about the same `Total bytes sent: 56,595`.

Comment: Try it without the `-z` (compression) option. If the connection is so slow you need compression, try it at the ssh level i.e. `-e "ssh -C"`.